# JSLint: Unexpected 'for'. Trying to iterate through object properties using for in

Tags: javascript, jslint

I am iterating over object properties with 'for in'. However, using JSLint's validation I receive the following warning:
    **Unexpected 'for'.**

Code snippet (Updated as requested):

```
var event = {
    data: {
        new_value: self.get_frequency_type()
    }
};

// Go through each condition and check for event listeners
var key;
for(key in self.conditions) {
    if(self.conditions.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    }
}
```

Is there any other way to iterate over object properties without triggering this warning?

Comment: try a space? `for (key in self.conditions) {
    if (self.conditions.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    }
}`

Comment: Did you miss a semicolon before the beginning of the for-loop? Can you expand your code to a few lines before the for starts?

Comment: @RyanO'Hara I have updated original question with code before it.

Comment: http://www.jslint.com/help.html#for

Comment: @mplungjan space did not help

Comment: See link and duplicate. The space did help on other errors.

Comment: @mplungjan using Object.keys as pointed in [link](http://www.jslint.com/help.html#forin) has solved the issue